# Array.indexOf(value) - not giving proper index number in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In GAS,

```
Code.gs
function myFunction() {
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActivesheet();
  var firstset = sheet2.getRange('B1:B10').getValues();
  Logger.log(firstset)
  var found = firstset.indexOf('[re]')
  Logger.log(found)
}
```

In Google Spreadsheet Range B1:B10,

```
B1  we
B2  we
B3  re
B4  ef
B5  ge
B6  er
B7  fe
B8  th
B9  rg
B10 pq
```

The answer to the code should result 2, however, Log is showing -1 (not matched). Any help

[Screenshot of Logger.log](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-dSvXeBVw2YU/UwckLlE3GmI/AAAAAAAAAG0/fyEd_ssbP6M/s595/Capture.JPG)

Comment: '[rel]' is a string, your array is not an array of strings but an array of arrays :-)

Comment: Thanks.....Is there any way to do it like this, I mean get index from array of arrays or convert array of arrays to array of strings

Answer (score 4):

in a simple for loop :

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var firstset = sheet2.getRange('B1:B10').getValues();
  for(var n in firstset){
    if(firstset[n][0]=='re'){break}
  }
  Logger.log(n);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Serge...will try, but does the `{break}` means stop the loop in case matched?

Answer (score 0):

If you would put your data in a row, not a column, the code could by used like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActivesheet();
  var firstset = sheet2.getRange('A1:J1').getValues();
  Logger.log(firstset)
  var found = firstset[0].indexOf('[re]')
  Logger.log(found)
}
```

`indexOf` - can search only in a one dimensional array - therefore is used in my example `firstset[0].indexOf('[re]')`

`.getValues()` - always returns 2 dimensional array, even there is only one row or column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me.

This is a revised method, the original was not giving me the proper results.

```
Array.prototype.findIndex = function(search)
{
  if(search == "") return -1;
  for(var t = 0; t < this.length; t++)
  {
    if(this[t].search(search) >=0)
    {break}
  }
  return t-1;
}
```

**USAGE**

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var index = fruits.findIndex("Apple");
//"Apple" is located at position 2 in the array.   
Logger.log("Index of 'Apple' is:  " + index);
```

**NOTE**

When using this method to get the index of a sheets column by name, increment the index by 1 to use sheet.getRange(rowIndex, columnIndex).

```
var range = sheet.getRange(row, (index+1));
```